# App Engine OAuth2.0 authorized cron job to analyze Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a Google App Engine project which is going to automatically trigger a function each 5 minutes to analyze a Google sheet.

**OAuth authorization**

The to-be-analyzed sheet is a G Suite sheet, public to only company members. So I need OAuth2 to authorize the access. How do I do this?

I think I need a Service Account client ID, because as this is going to run automatically in the server, there cannot be a OAuth2 flow, right? Who is going to click the buttons if the function is ran in the server?

I need some directions.

Thanks

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

- Setup a new App Engine service account (I don't know if a "new" one was neccesary really)
- Take note of that new service account email
- Share the Sheet with that service account mail (I've not yet tested it without this step)
- Download its service secrets as a JSON.
- Use this code(inspired in (1) and (2))

  ```
  class analysisHandler(Handler):
      def get(self):

          credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('service-secrets.json',
                             ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"])

          http = httplib2.Http()

           #if credentials are still valid
          if not credentials.invalid:
              logging.info("Valid credentials, entering main function")
              http = credentials.authorize(http)
              main(http)
          else:
              credentials.refresh(http)
              main(http)
  ```

Then in main():

```
sheetService = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=authorized_http)
logging.info("Reading Google Sheet")
result = sheetService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute(http=authorized_http)

urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)
logging.info("Printing in Google Sheet")
sheetService.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="Log", body=body, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED").execute(http=authorized_http)
```

Where the `authorized_http` parameter is the one built before with credentials.authorize()

I think this can be improved however.

(1) [How to use "Service account" authorization (rather than user based access refresh tokens)](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/wiki/How-to-use-%22Service-account%22-authorization-(rather-than-user-based-access-refresh-tokens))

(2) [Creating and sharing Google Sheet spreadsheets using Python](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/f988a5a83a301dd27469)

Comment: But you do realize that with this approach the spreadsheet is no longer "public to only company members" (since it's shared with an outside entity), right?

Comment: Oh yes, with the service account, thanks for pointing out. That will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an OAuth2 flow, but not one involving a manual user operation - the actions are performed by the servers, automatically, based on pre-configured information. From the very document you mentioned:

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions
>   such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this
>   scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs
>   to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your
>   application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so
>   users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called
>   "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth"
>   refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on
>   behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.)

Basically you need:

- on the GAE side to locate an existing (or create a new) service account for your app (in the cloud project's IAM & Admin [Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) page). One service account is automatically created when your app is created.
- on the G Suite side to allow access by [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority):

> To delegate domain-wide authority to a service account, first enable
>   domain-wide delegation for an existing service account in the Service
>   accounts page or create a new service account with domain-wide
>   delegation enabled.
>
> Then, an administrator of the G Suite domain must complete the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Go to your G Suite domain’s Admin console.
> 2. Select Security from the list of controls. If you don't see Security listed, select More controls from the gray bar at the bottom
>      of the page, then select Security from the list of controls. If you
>      can't see the controls, make sure you're signed in as an administrator
>      for the domain.
> 3. Select Show more and then Advanced settings from the list of options.
> 4. Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section.
> 5. In the Client Name field enter the service account's Client ID. You can find your service account's client ID in the [Service accounts
>      page](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts).
> 6. In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example, if your
>      application needs domain-wide access to the Google Drive API and the
>      Google Calendar API, enter: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,
>      https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
> 7. Click Authorize.
>
> Your application now has the authority to make API calls as users in
>   your domain (to "impersonate" users). When you prepare to make
>   authorized API calls, you specify the user to impersonate.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid involving the G Suite Admin... I actually practically don't have access to it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since in G Suite is where the document access control is enforced.

Comment: I finally did it without the domain-wide solution, I'm still scratching my head, but it works. Will post the solution. Thanks for your help.