# GAE Python: Control access based on GSuite group

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to control access to a request handler entirely or some parts therein based on what GSuite for Education/Business group a user belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have code check the GSuite group membership using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) from the [Google Apps Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/). You'd probably be interested in one of:

- [retrieve all groups for a member](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups)
- [retrieve a group's member](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#get_member) (if just one or a few groups are to be checked).

You'll need to

- [Enable the API access in the G Suite Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en):

> G Suite administrators have access to the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/)–a collection
>   of Application Programming Interfaces (APIs). With these APIs, you can
>   build customized administrative tools for your G Suite products.
>   Before you can use the Admin SDK, you need to enable API access in the
>   Google Admin console.
>
> You must be signed in as a [super administrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986#super_admin) for this task.
>   Enable API access
>
> To verify that API access is enabled:
>
> 1. [Sign in](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076) to your [Google Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076).
>
>    Sign in using an administrator account, not your current account some_user@gmail.com.
> 2. From the Admin console dashboard, go to **Security** > **API reference**.
>
>    To see Security on the dashboard, you might have to click **More controls** at the bottom.
> 3. Make sure the **Enable API access** box is checked.
> 4. At the bottom, click **Save**.

- enable the `Admin SDK` API from the `Google Apps APIs` group in for your GAE app's [API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) page
- [install the Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine) in your GAE app (if not already done)
- address authentication, posibly using your GAE app's [service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts). See Google API Client Libraries [Authentication Overview](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_overview). And maybe related [App Engine OAuth2.0 authorized cron job to analyze Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182137/app-engine-oauth2-0-authorized-cron-job-to-analyze-google-sheet).
- (if you want to) restrict app access to only your GSuite domain, see [Restrict App Engine access to G Suite accounts on custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943712/restrict-app-engine-access-to-g-suite-accounts-on-custom-domain)
- code your access control logic using the directory api to obtain group membership info

Comment: Do you know how to achieve SSO with GAE? A doc would be enough. Since I'm new to SSO, I don't know where to start. Our backend is built using flask (GAE) and our frontend is built using Angular2.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Personally I used Google Identity Toolkit (the Python Web recipe) for that: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/